# Do these two articles appear in Trek Magazine and Best of Trek?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-ds9

Two articles by Mark A Golding, "Shortcuts Though Space in Star Trek" and "Subspace Radio and Space Warps" advocate the theory that much interstellar travel in *Star Trek* is done through wormholes or other space warps that allow instant travel between stars, thus explaining many of the problems with the duration and distance of various interstellar trips in *Star Trek*.

They were published in *Trek: The Magazine for Star Trek Fans* number 11, July 1978, and number 14, Fall 1979, and in *The Best of Trek*, 1978, and *The Best of Trek 2*, 1980.

Those articles also mention a theory that explains some problems in *Star Trek* chronology by saying that Earth invented forms of rapid interstellar travel twice in *Star Trek* history - once by a secret group unknown to the rest of humanity and later by the rest of humanity - and the two groups reunited by the era of TOS.

I would be grateful if anyone who has access to *Trek* and the *Best of Trek* books could confirm that those articles do include the theory that in *Star Trek* Earth developed forms of rapid interstellar travel twice.

I would also like to know if anyone knows of any other discussion of the idea that Earth might have developed forms of rapid interstellar travel twice in *Star Trek*.

Comment: “i would be grateful if anyone who has access to Trek and the Best of Trek books could confirm that those articles do include the theory that in Star Trek Earth developed forms of rapid interstellar travel twice.” — so you’re not sure if the articles you mentioned include that theory or not?

Comment: I suspect that the major issues are the deep-space vessels seen in shows like "Space Seed". If the Enterprise is exploring unknown space, why do they keep coming upon Earth vessels.

Comment: Paul D. Waite - I know that they contain that theory.  I would like other people to answer the question by stating they have looked at those articles and they do contain that theory.  that would make this question an online reference to the theory in the articles - probably the only online reference.

Answer (score 5):

I can confirm that [*The Best of Trek 2*](https://stexpanded.fandom.com/wiki/The_Best_of_Trek_2) (archived [here](https://archive.org/stream/TheBestOfTrek2/The%20Best%20of%20Trek%202_djvu.txt), unfortunately with relatively poor OCR) does indeed contain this article and that the article does indeed postulate that subspace radio is somehow performed via wormholes (which it describes as "gateways") and that there were two different ages of human FTL travel.

> It seems rather illogical to explore thousands of times as  far in one
>   direction as another. Of course, Earth had two  separate phases of
>   interstellar exploration, according to my  historical reconstruction.
>
> First Zefrem Cochrane of Alpha Centauri led a fleet from  Earth which
>   traveled through hundreds or thousands of  Gateways, and then
>   destroyed their records so that the  route back to Earth would never
>   be discovered by their  enemies. Then they founded a new Earth and
>   formed the  realm which overthrew the evil power which had monop- 
>   olized interstellar travel. They then began the long, slow  search by
>   trial and error for the route back to Earth.
>
> Later the slower-than-Iight ships of Earth discovered the  Gateways
>   and explored through them, colonizing many  planets and fighting the
>   Romulan War and the War with  Axanar. The reunion of the two groups
>   was only a few yean  in the past at the time of the first visit of the
>   Enterprise to  Talos IV, and the resulting area of explored space
>   extended  hundreds of Gateways long in the connecting axis between 
>   the two former spheres of exploration.

It should be noted that although some of the math seems sound enough, Mark's supposed "*historical recreation*" is **100% pure fanfic.**